Error: "Window.localStorage getter: Forbidden in a sandboxed document" in Next.js app
I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application where some users receive the following error message:
Window.localStorage getter: Forbidden in a sandboxed document without the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

This error occurs despite not using any iframes in my application. Here's a sample of the code that's causing the issue:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const STORAGE_KEY = 'top-banner'

export default function TopBanner() {
   const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

     useEffect(() => {
        if(!localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)) setDisabled(false)
      }, [])

   if (disabled) return;

   return (<p>Banner</p>)
}

Additional Details:

Environment: Next.js with React
Problem Context: The error seems to occur randomly for some users, and not consistently for all.
Third-Party Scripts: I am using some third-party scripts for analytics and advertising.

Questions:

What could be causing this error in an environment where no explicit iframes are used?
Could third-party scripts be the reason behind this error, even if they're included directly?
How can I resolve or work around this issue to ensure localStorage can be accessed safely?


How frequent does this happen? How did you get this error message (e.g. from client side logging)? Did any user complain and you are sure they have this error?

Sounds unlikely, but could it be that your application is being loaded within a sandboxed iframe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#allow-same-origin

@Damzaky I am getting those errors from sentry and sometimes users tells me they have a Client error black page, they reload and everything is fine.

@ravindUwU I tried to load it from an iframe and I have no issues, it should depend on browsers

I think you can start with logging this information: check if it's accessed in iframe: window.self !== window.top, then log document.referrer, it should show the parent URL that accesses your page (your error shows allow-same-origin, so we can check the parent URL)

Is there any thing consistent about when these errors occur. Maybe on a specific browser? Also are you calling local storage in a client component?

I am not using it in any iframe, maybe someone is whowing the website in an iframe without my autorization.
@Ethan only on firefox

@Ajouve Could you include a minimal reproducible example either in the form of a link of a github repo.

usually thirdpary advertising scripts try to inject iframe or access local storage in someway, would recommend you to check the script
